# Vscode not detecting custom types for jsdoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am defining a custom type as follows:

```
/**
 *  function to create external storage storage vendor CR or resources.
 *  @export
 *  @callback CreatePayloadFunction
 *  @param {string} storageClass
 *  The name of the of the storage class required for creation of storage class resource.
 *
 *  @param {string} systemName
 *  The name of the external storage system requried for the creation of the external custom resource.
 *
 *  @param {Object} form
 *  The other fields of the create storage class form.
 *
 *  @param {Object} model
 *  The model referring the `apiGroup`,`apiVersion` and `kind` of the external storage provider's CRD.
 *
 *  @returns {{ model: ExtensionK8sModel; payload: K8sResourceKind }[]}}
 */
```

In the same file I am using this as follows:

```
export type ExternalStorage = {
  /** Display name of the external storage vendor. */
  displayName: string;

  /** The model referring the `apiGroup`,`apiVersion` and `kind` of the external storage provider's CRD. */
  model: ExtensionK8sModel;


  /** @type {CreatePayloadFunction} */
  createPayload: CreatePayload;
};
```

When I am exporting the object as:

```
export const SUPPORTED_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: ExternalStorage[] = [
  {
    displayName: 'Red Hat Ceph Storage',
    model: {
      group: OCSServiceModel.apiGroup,
      version: OCSServiceModel.apiVersion,
      kind: OCSServiceModel.kind,
    },
    Component: null,
    createPayload: null,
  },
```

I am seeing that vscode only analyzing the object as {CreatePayloadFunction}

[image]

How shall I make vscode to identify the types ?

Comment: Did you solve it?